# Что рекомендуют сейчас для разработки ПО, а что запрещено?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, intellij-idea

Сейчас много говорят о переходе на отечественное ПО и об отказе от иностранного.
Где можно посмотреть почитать какие программы рекомендуется использовать для разработки ПО а от каких стоит отказаться?
Visual studio, intellij idea, sql сервера какие именно стоит сейчас использовать?

Comment: Не слышал, чтобы что-то было запрещено. Разве что использование пиратского ПО, но это не зависит от года.

Comment: Просто рекомендации, дабы в момент не потерять всё. Аналогов всегда много

Comment: Сейчас рекомендуют сменить «отечество»

Comment: @MaxDown А что можно потерять при переходе к другой `IDE` - настройки своей `IDE`?

Comment: @CrazyElf не все IDE одинаково полезны (зачеркнуто) удобны

Comment: @insolor Поэтому лучше заранее переехать на менее удобные, но те, которые не исчезнут из доступа? )

Comment: @CrazyElf, ну да, на какой-нибудь VIM, например (нет, спасибо). Никуда не переходить, пока не потребуется. В принципе, можно к любому IDE приспособиться (даже если это листок бумаги), и заранее дергаться тут нет особого смысла.

Comment: @insolor Ну вот и я о том же )